# Python: Cann't connect to HDFS files

Tags: python, hadoop, pyarrow

I have already tried many different ways but non of them does not work. For example, the followng way failed with the error "The system cannot find the file specified."

Example:

```
import pyarrow as pa
fs = pa.hdfs.connect('192.168.100.45', 20500, 'hdfs')

path='/user/hive/warehouse/sample_07/sample_07'
with fs.open(path, 'r') as f:
    print(f)
```

Error

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

```
HDFS File System IMAGE:
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iylhI.jpg)

```
Full error print screen:
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QOld.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6NGS.jpg)

Comment: Please show your hdfs filesystem to prove that it exists

Comment: `fs.open` is unable to raise `FileNotFoundError`. Can you please post a complete stack trace

Comment: Wes McKinney: full error attached

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? I am facing exactly the same issue. T

Comment: No I didn't. I began to work with Hive & Impala DB tables, not HDFS files.

Comment: struggling with the same issue. It seems like you have to set some environment variables before you can actually use the function [source](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/python/doc/source/filesystems.rst)